# Do data sources travel with a particular mail merge document?

Tags: sql-server, mail-merge, microsoft-word-2003

Do data sources that you set up (particularly to SQL Server) travel with a mail merge document?

In other words, if I set up data sources in a mail merge document on my machine and then save and send that document to a co-worker and she opens it on her machine, will the data sources still be there when she opens it? Or, will she have to set them up again herself?

Comment: I'm guessing they will. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

a way to tell for sure

```
Sub view_datasource()
MsgBox ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.Name
End Sub
```